# Regex get a specific word within parentheses

Tags: regex

I have this text:

> Melee longspear (reach 10 feet, agile) +17, Damage 2d8+7 piercing within its reach. (reach)

And I want to replace all reach words within parentheses by KK:

> Melee longspear (KK 10 feet, agile) +17, Damage 2d8+7 piercing within its reach. (KK)

I've tried some regexp expressions, but none is working. Any idea? (I work with php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't have nested/unbalanced parenthesis in your text, you can use this regex to match `reach` only within parenthesis and replace with `KK`

```
reach(?=[^()]*\))
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uuPogW/1)**